# How to quantitatively measure the learning complexity in comparing regression and classification task?

Tags: regression, classification

For the case of same input and same output, we can map the relationship with regression.

Meanwhile, we try it with multi-label classification, by masking the output with simple binary mask : when there is a nonzero value, it becomes 1, and 0 for the zero value.

By qualitatively thinking about the two processes, it seems that the multi-label classification has somewhat lower model complexity because it only answers binary question (while regression should fit the exact value).

Is there any nice explanation about the situation in a quantitative way?

Just throwing me about the related mathematics would give me a direction of thought.